# Wsus superseded update

Tags: wsus

I have a new update to be deployed, and its superseding another update, how can i confirm if its "the superseded update" should be approved or declined ?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is usually a link in the details of the update that will take you to the details of the update that has been superseded.  You can follow the link and see if you need it or not.

Comment: if i declined it, will i be able to approve it again ?

Comment: It will still show if you filter by "all updates".